# How create multilingual jsp web pages so that one could show mixed fonts in same page

Tags: jsp, fonts, internationalization, webfonts

How can I create jsp website that can show mixed fonts in the same page something like this.

```
<div lang="hi" font="hindi>
      some text in hindi language
</div>

<div lang="en" font="english">
      normal english language
</div>
```

I got this [link](http://webservices.nic.in/ResourceCentre/hindiweb.aspx) on the internet. This talks about Dynamic Font and EOT files.  Is this the correct and latest way to achieve this.

Also it should be visible on web pages on any operating system regardless the fonts installed in their systems.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to display fonts on a website is to use `@font-face` within your CSS, which allows multiple fonts regardless of the browser/operating system or anything else. Several fonts faces typically exist, .

Some multilingual fonts are suggested on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32059298/4258817)

EOF is used for Internet Explorer, WOFF or the newer WOFF2 for web use is a compressed version of OpenType (OTF)  and TrueType (TTF) fonts and are most common on browsers.

[More info and using @font-face](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) 
I can't open your link without logging in.